# showing result to erb from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, erb

Currently I'm working with Rails.

I have erb form and what I want to do is showing the result of function
in controller to erb

```
def total_ratings
    total_ratings = 1000
    Score.where('ratings_count > ?', 0).each do |score|
      total_ratings += score.ratings_count
    end

    render total_ratings
end
```

After I get total_ratings as number,

I tried to show the total_ratings like this in erb form

```
<div class="page-header-description">ratings : <%= score_total_ratings_scoring_index_path %></div>
```

But this only printed out the path, not the result. Which point I missed in here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your function from controller to the helper module to render in in the view.

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def total_ratings
    total_ratings = 1000
    Score.where('ratings_count > ?', 0).each do |score|
      total_ratings += score.ratings_count
    end

    total_ratings
  end
end
```

Now render it in the view:

```
<div class="page-header-description">ratings : <%= total_ratings %></div>
```

Read more about Rails [`helpers`](https://mixandgo.com/blog/the-beginners-guide-to-rails-helpers)

Comment: what should I do if I put this in controller. Do I have to use json? @

Зелёный

Comment: The purpose of controller functions is about request handling not a views helpers.

Comment: I put above function in routing as :get, and how about using render json form? to show the nubmers. Actually, above function will be later transformed which can differentiated along dates.

Comment: There is no way to do it with Ruby only, you should use js and fetch json data from that route after page is loading.

Comment: how can I fetch that. I have made json like this

Comment: `result = {}
result['scores'] = total_ratings`

`render json: result`

Comment: it's hard to help you because of lack your knowledge. Use google _rails ajax  json loading_ .

Comment: @jh.shin, I think you should use the given answer. If u still want to use controller method, then use instance variable like `@total_ratings`. However, I wont recommend that.

Comment: thanks all, I should re-study this part. And I've added to the helper